# Android Map Shows Direction Images in ListView

Tags: android, google-maps

My android application uses android mapView.It shows location map and driving direction in an listview like google map.Now i want to show images corresponding to directions in lisview. ie, if the **direction is to left**,then i want to s**how an image which indicate to turn left in the listview**.
How can i solve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I did this using String operations, but it is not stable, give 90% accuracy. See the code below:

```
        Drawable draw;
        if(direction.contains("Slight right"))
        {
            draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slightright);
        }
        else if(direction.contains("Slight left"))
        {
            draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slightleft);
        }
        else if(direction.contains("right"))
        {
            if(direction.contains("left"))
            {
                int index = direction.indexOf("right");
                int index2 = direction.indexOf("left");
                if(index<index2)
                {
                    draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.turnright);
                }
                else
                {
                    draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.turnleft);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.turnright);
            }
        }
        else if(direction.contains("left"))
        {
            draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.turnleft);
        }
        else if(direction.contains("roundabout") && direction.contains("exit"))
        {
            draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundabout);
        }
        else if(direction.contains("Continue"))
        {
            draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.straight);
        }
        else if(direction.contains("U-turn"))
        {
            draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uturn);
        }
        else
        {
            draw=null;
        }

        //then set the drawable to your ImageView
```

You can play around with the code if you see something missing or you have more images.

These are the images I used:

[image: slightleft][image: slightright]

[image: turnleft][image: turnright]

[image: roundabout][image: straight][image: Uturn]

Comment: Thank you Hesham.Do you how it is implemented in google places or google map??